# Sorting for view model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2017

I have a view model that combines data from 3 models.

```
  public class VendorVM
    {
        public IEnumerable<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Promo> Promos { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Distributor> Distributors { get; set; }
    }
```

Here's the controller:

```
     public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? id)
            {
ViewData["NameSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
            ViewData["DateSortParm"] = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

           var viewModel = new VendorVM();
                    viewModel.Vendors = await _context.Vendors
                        .Include(i => i.Promos)
                        .Include(i => i.Contacts)
                        .Include(i => i.Distributors)
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .ToListAsync();
                    if (id != null)
                    {
                        ViewData["VendorID"] = id.Value;
                        Vendor vendorVM = viewModel.Vendors.Where(
                            i => i.VendorID == id.Value).Single();
                        viewModel.Promos = vendorVM.Promos.ToList();
                        viewModel.Contacts = vendorVM.Contacts.ToList();
                        viewModel.Distributors = vendorVM.Distributors.ToList();

 switch(sortOrder)
                {
                    case "name_desc":
                        viewModel.Vendors = viewModel.Vendors.OrderByDescending(i => i.VendorName);
                        break;
                    case "Date":
                        viewModel.Vendors = viewModel.Vendors.OrderBy(i => i.Distributors.OrderBy(v => v.LastUpdateDate));
                        break;
                    case "date_desc":
                        viewModel.Vendors = viewModel.Vendors.OrderByDescending(i => i.Distributors.OrderByDescending(v => v.LastUpdateDate)));
                        break;
                    default:
                        viewModel.Vendors = viewModel.Vendors.OrderBy(i => i.VendorName);
                        break;
                    }
                    return View(viewModel);
    }
```

How can I add sorting functionality to this view model? I want to sort by VendorName & LastUpdateDate. I'm following this tutorial here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page. It doesn't work for my view model as I can only sort Vendors info. I would like to sort promos, contacts & distributors info as well.

Comment: What do you want to sort on?

Comment: You'd generally sort a collection with `.OrderBy()`.  What do you mean by "it doesn't work for view models"?  What did you try and how did it fail?

Comment: @WellerEE name & date

Comment: @David Well using the method from the MVC EF Core tutorial I can only sort the Vendors fields. I want to be able to sort Contacts, Distributors & Promos as well.

Comment: @VyNguyen: What's stopping you?  Where do you try and how does it fail?  Why are those any different?

Comment: @David in the controller & the view. I followed exactly what the tutorial says.

Comment: @VyNguyen: I see no attempt to sort anything in the controller code you're showing us, and you're not showing us the view.  Where do you try to use `.OrderBy()`?  And, more specifically to the point of the question, in what way is it not working?

Comment: I think you would like to sort the lists independently ?

Comment: Do you think it is wise to retrieve **all** vendors from db including **all** those collection properties just to pick the collections from one? How many vendors do you plan to manage? Hopefully just a few or you will need a lot of coffee ;o)

Comment: @David I just updated my post. I didn't post my sorting code because it's already in the tutorial plus it doesn't work.

Comment: @VyNguyen: Yes, well, if you want us to help you understand why your code doesn't work, then actually showing us the code that doesn't work is generally a good start.  Now, in your `switch` statement it looks like you're only ever sorting the `Vendors` collection.  Is that working?  What happens when you try to also sort the other collections?

Comment: @SirRufo Possibly, but what do you mean "just to pick the collections from one"?

Comment: @VyNguyen after if ( id != null ) you assign the three collection properties  from one vendor to the viewmodel. So you only need these collections from a single vendor. But you request and retrieve these collections for all vendors in your statement above the if, and that will be a huge datatransfer when your data will increase in production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what you're trying to do here:

```
viewModel.Vendors = viewModel.Vendors.OrderBy(i => i.Distributors.OrderBy(v => v.LastUpdateDate));
```

The semantics of that don't really make sense to me, and I'm sure the compiler is equally confused.  Are you trying to sort both the `Vendors` and the `Distributors` collections?  That would be two separate sorting operations.  Something like this:

```
viewModel.Vendors = viewModel.Vendors.OrderBy(i => i.LastUpdateDate));
viewModel.Distributors = viewModel.Distributors.OrderBy(v => v.LastUpdateDate));
```

When you have an operation on one collection that you want to perform on another collection, you just do the same thing to that other collection.  These statements don't somehow nest into one another.

Answer (score 0):

I would use .Order By(...) On my original query before the tolistasync call